# Squarefree monomial ideals have a decomposition as the intersection of monomial prime ideals.

Tags: commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

We've proven the following theorem in class:

> Every monomial ideal has a presentation $$I = \bigcap_{i=1}^m Q_i,$$ where each $Q_i = (x_{i_1}^{a_1}, \dots , x_{i_k}^{a_k})$.

I've tried proving the result in question by observing that it suffices to show each $a_i=1.$ Then I'm thinking assuming to the contrary might be the right direction and so if there is some $t$ such that $a_t \ge 2$ and we might bring about a contradiction to the fact that $I$ is a squarefree monomial ideal. I'm stuck with how to do this though, and not even sure if my approach is the right one. Please help?

Comment: I don't get your idea: do you mean that's enough to assume $a_i=1$? How so? This can work only if $I$ is generated by squarefree monomials.

Comment: @user26857: What I'm saying is that if all the $a_i$'s were shown to be $\le 1$, then the $Q_i$'s would infact be the monomial prime ideals and the proof would be complete. It is indeed given that $I$ is a squarefree monomial ideal.

Comment: I still don't get it: do you want a proof only for $I$ squarefree, or do you mean that a proof for $I$ squarefree leads to the general case?

Comment: @user26857 I'm getting confused too now. I think I only want a proof for the $I$ is squarefree case. The theorem's already proven that $I$ can be expressed as an intersection of ideals generated by the pure powers of variables. That if $I$ is squarefree then $Q_i$'s are prime is what needs to be proved.

Comment: I think both cases can be proved by using the same idea (which can be found in my answer). I don't think there is something special about squarefree monomial ideals in this respect. Anyway, this leads immediately to a decomposition of squarefree monomial ideals as an intersection of monomial prime ideals.

Comment: for future readers, might be helpful https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55371/are-squarefree-monomial-ideals-on-a-regular-system-of-parameters-in-a-regular-lo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is the following: if the generating set of $I$ contains a monomial which is not a power of a single variable, then write it as $m_1m_2$ with $\gcd(m_1,m_2)=1$, and notice that $I=(J,m_1)\cap (J,m_2)$, where $J$ is the monomial ideal having the same generators as $I$ excepting $m_1m_2$.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. Say $I$ is squarefree to begin with. We decompose $I$ as you showed and then all the factors will be squarefree aswell and hence prime. Correct?

Comment: @user264885 Yes, it's correct.

Comment: how would you show that $I \subseteq (J,m_1) \cap (J,m_2)$

Comment: Why $(J,m_1)$,  $ (J,m_2)$ are primes?

Comment: Did I say they are prime?