# Prove $\langle x \rangle + \cap P_i = \cap (\langle x \rangle + P_i)$ for monomials ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, monomial-ideals

I'm trying to follow the proof of [this fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688396/squarefree-monomial-ideals-have-a-decomposition-as-the-intersection-of-monomial#comment5436781_1688396) on [this book](https://books.google.es/books?id=a12DAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA12&dq=squarefree%20monomial%20ideal%20is%20the%20intersection%20of%20prime%20ideals&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJuL_rrYfZAhWFXBQKHUvDD-MQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=squarefree%20monomial%20ideal%20is%20the%20intersection%20of%20prime%20ideals&f=false) on Gröbner basis. At one point of the proof they use this equality that I do not fully understad. I wonder if it is evident:

> Given prime monomial ideals $P_i$ (which are generated by sets of
>   variables) in $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ and another variable $x$ (that may
>   or not be a generator in some ideals $P_i$) then I would need to show
>   that $\langle x \rangle + \cap P_i = \cap (\langle x \rangle + P_i)$
>   where intersections are finite.

The inclusion $\subseteq$ is clear. For the other one I'm having more problems. The intuition is that each $\cap P_i$ is computed by taking $lcm(X_i,X_j) = X_iX_j$ and therefore consists of monomials. Can you help me to prove the other inclusion?

Comment: This is quite easy. First of all assume that you have only two prime ideals. If a monomial $m$ belongs to $(x,P_1)\cap(x,P_2)$ then it is divisible by $x$ (and you are done) or by some generator of $P_1$ *and* $P_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $J$ is a monomial ideal and $(I_i)_i$ is a family of monomial ideals of $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ then
$$ \bigcap_{i} (J+I_i) = J + \bigcap_i I_i.$$
This is easy to prove. The inclusion $\supseteq$ is clear. Conversely, let $u\in \bigcap_{i} (J+I_i)$ be a monomial. If $u\in J$ then there is nothing to prove. If $u\notin J$, since $u\in J+I_i$, then $u\in I_i$. Hence $u\in \bigcap_i I_i$.